# Using "Where" for asking about studying under a person

Tags: prepositions, pronouns, interrogatives

Given the sentence:

> The four youths studied under the famous professor.

Can I ask my students like this?

> Where did the four youths study?

Is it suitable to use the question word "Where"  for asking about person?

Comment: Can you tell us what subject you are teaching, @learner ? Or do you mean to ask the question "Can I ask my students like this?" from the viewpoint of the "famous professor?"

Comment: No, I mean from my viewpoint.

Comment: I teach English.

Answer (score 1):

The 5 W's of journalism are who, what, where, when and why.

Where typically refers to a place.

The phrase "four youth" is really odd too.

So as an American English speaker I'd ask:

> Who did four youngsters study under?

Comment: Or _Who did the four youths study under?_ Or _Who did the four kids study under?_

Comment: @P. E. Dant - "youths" is a really odd word in American English - if it is a word. I was trying to use some form of young and youngsters was the only word that came to mind. Youngsters is a proper but uncommon word. I'd probably use students.

Comment: I hear the mass noun _youth_ frequently in Black American communities: "The youth did such-and-such." I also hear the plural "youths" in those communities quite frequently, and in police communications ("five youths were seen loitering...") Not so odd as you might think, in sum. But by far the most common noun is _kid._

Comment: I'd say "youth" as a noun is a relatively rare word in American English, but not unheard of. Yes, I'd be more likely to say "four students" or "four teenagers" if they're teenagers or "four children" (if they're younger than teenagers or "four young people" if they're in their late teens to maybe early 20s. "Youth" is still used pretty commonly as a collective noun, like "The youth in this country today are lazy". Churches often refer to theirs clubs for teenagers as "the youth group".

Comment: @Jay I posit that you do not interface with the left in minority communities, particularly Black communities; "the youth," "youth" and "youths" are ubiquitous objects of concern among those cadres. You would be hard pressed to find a broadside that omits one or the other usage.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I intended to allude to that sort of usage with my "youth in this country today" example.

Answer (score 1):

If by *under* you mean that they are physically situated below the professor, then *where* is a possibility, but I assume by *under* you mean that they are instructed or supervised by the professor, in which case *where* will not be understood. The answer to *Where did the four youths study?* will be a location— a room, a laboratory, a university, a city, and so forth.

The natural way to express the question would be

> Who did the four youths study under?

though pedants might inquire

> Under whom did the four youths study?

Comment: _Who'd they study with?_